# Heuristic to find the maximum weight independent set in an arbritary graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, linear-programming, np-complete

The MWIS (Maximum weight independent set) is a NP-complete problem, so if P!=NP we cannot find a solution in a good enough time complexity.

I am looking for an algorithm that can find an approximation of the MWIS in an arbitrary graph within a good time complexity. I am currently working on a connected graph with 128 nodes and 3051 edges.

I have found [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/devavrat/www/bp-mwis.pdf), but it seems that it is only working for bipartite graph with an unique MWIS.

I will be glad if anyone can help me with some references or even better with a pseudo-code of a working algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to formulate this as the following problem. Suppose each vertex *v* in the graph has weight *w(v)*. You define a variable *x(v)*, and use some out-of-the-box linear programming solver to solve

*max \sum_v w(v) x(v)* (maximize the weight of chosen vertices)

subject to

*x(u) + x(v) <= 1, (u, v) \in E* (don't take neighbors)

and

*x(v) \in {0, 1}* (can only choose to take or not take a vertex)

---

This is a combinatorical problem (the last constraint is exponential in the number of vertices). There are two ways to continue from here:

- Switch the last constraint to

  *x(v) \in [0, 1]* (extent to which you choose a vertex)

  solve it with an LP solver, and continue along [this paper, 4.3](http://www.ru.is/~mmh/papers/WIS_WG.pdf).
- In the comment below, David Eisenstat claims that for the sizes of your graph, an integer solver will do just fine (and yield better results)

Comment: From experience, for a graph of the size that the question mentions, it's likely that just by switching the constraint x(v) in [0, 1] to x(v) in {0, 1} (making an integer program), the solver itself will return the optimal solution. Otherwise, the solver's heuristics for integer programs are likely to be better in practice than the rounding method described in the linked paper.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat OK, thanks. Have incorporated your comment.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try both.

I would like to be sure that the LP relaxation that I need to solve is max( w(v) x(v)), subject to (x(v1) + x(v2) <= 1) if v1 and v2 are neighbors.
And do you have any LP Solver and IP Solver written in C++ that I can use easily ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for finding a minimum weighted-degree vertex for MWIS, as suggested in the paper referenced by @Ami.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
graph = nx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph(50,10)
for u in graph:
    graph.nodes[u]['weight'] = np.random.uniform(0,1)

adj_0 = nx.adj_matrix(graph).todense()
a = -np.array([graph.nodes[u]['weight'] for u in graph.nodes])
IS = -np.ones(adj_0.shape[0])
while np.any(IS==-1):
    rem_vector = IS == -1
    adj = adj_0.copy()
    adj = adj[rem_vector, :]
    adj = adj[:, rem_vector]

    u = np.argmin(a[rem_vector].dot(adj!=0)/a[rem_vector])
    n_IS = -np.ones(adj.shape[0])
    n_IS[u] = 1
    neighbors = np.argwhere(adj[u,:]!=0)
    if neighbors.shape[0]:
        n_IS[neighbors] = 0
    IS[rem_vector] = n_IS
print IS
```

IS is the minimal weighted independent set.

Comment: Hi @pg2455, does this algorithm find the exact Maximum Weight Independent Set ?

Comment: I can't edit my above comment but have just re-read it properly: can this algorithm be used to find the maximum weighted independent set ?

Comment: This is a heuristic to find a minimal (not minimum) WIS. You can negate your weights and use this heuristic to find a maximal (not maximum) WIS. The heuristic does a job of finding a solution satisfying a criterion (independent set property), but it doesn't prove that it's exact optimal. Because WIS is an NP-Hard problem, it won't be possible to find a maximum WIS without proving the optimality of a solution. You might have to use an exact solver for that. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah I see- thanks ! The idea of using negative weights hadn't occured to me. Would you happen to know of any exact solvers that simply brute force a problem ? I'm trying to find the MIS for some small graphs!

Comment: I think you can very well just use an integer linear programming formulation of MIS and use any off the shelf solvers like SCIP. It will give you all possible MIS.

Answer (score 1):

To solve MWIS, you can use a a maximum weight clique solver on the complement graph. [TSM-MWC](https://home.mis.u-picardie.fr/%7Ecli/EnglishPage.html) is a fast algorithm implemented in C. If you graphs aren't too large, you may be able to solve the problem using Networkx in Python: here are reference pages for the [`complement`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.unary.complement.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.unary.complement) and [`max_weight_clique`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.max_weight_clique.html) functions.