# Algorithm that optimally divide objects into given groups with given weights

Tags: algorithm

I don't know how correctly describe the problem, so I will give an example. Basically I want an algorithm that optimally divide objects into given groups. That given groups have given weights. Аs a result, the algorithm should give a set of groups with the maximum total weight. Each object can be only in one group, also object does not have to be in a some group.

Example:

Given objects - o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8

Given groups with their weights:

- g1 - (o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8) - 30
- g2 - (o1, o2, o3, o4, o5) - 30
- g3 - (o1, o2, o3) - 10
- g4 - (o4, o5) - 10
- g5 - (o6, o7) - 10
- g6 - (o1, o2, o3, o4) - 25
- g7 - (o5, o6, o7) - 25

Best solution here is (g6, g7) - it gives (25 + 25) = 50

Some of not best solutions:

- (g1) - 30
- (g3, g4, g5) - 30
- (g3, g7) - 35
- (g6, g5) - 35

Possible solution is:

- determine all possible sets of disjoint groups
- calculate total weight for each set
- set with maximum total weight is the answer

But I think it will take too long with a lot of groups and objects. Is there a faster solution? I feel like this is some kind of known issue with a known solution - am I right? If not - is there known similar issues that can help?

Comment: What are the constraints, Seems like DP with bitmask.

Comment: How many objects/groups do you have in the real use case?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the weighted graph G, where:

- The set of vertices V = {g1, g2, ..., g7} is your set of groups;
- Two groups gi and gj share an edge if and only if their intersection is non-empty (in other words, there exists an object o_k which is in both groups);
- Each vertex has a weight, which is the weight of the group.

Then your problem is exactly the [**maximum-weight independent set problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Finding_independent_sets).

This problem is NP-complete in general, but it has been studied a lot. If your instance is small, or if you have additional assumptions, then exact algorithms and approximation algorithms exist.

You do not mention how big your actual problem is. I assume you have more than 7 groups. Here is a solution using integer linear programming: [Heuristic to find the maximum weight independent set in an arbitrary graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921996/heuristic-to-find-the-maximum-weight-independent-set-in-an-arbritary-graph)